# Setting up input to update scope variables doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller:

```
.controller("myController", function($scope){
  $scope.name = "Test";
  $scope.desc = "Hello World!";

  $scope.create = function(){
    var test = {name: $scope.name, desc: $scope.desc}
    console.log(test);
  }
}
```

and the template:

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">{{primaryName}}</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{sampleName}} Name" value="{{name}}">
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">{{primaryName}}</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{sampleName}} Name" value="{{desc}}">
</label>
<a ng-click="create()">Create Test</a>
```

It seems that when it runs, the input gets set to *Test* So i change it to what I want. *Alpha* and click Create.  It will console.log out *Test*

I dont know if i am doing assignment correctly.  I thought I was, but it seems to be otherwise.

What am i doing wrong?

*Edit*  I also attempted to have the create function accept variables, and passed those in, still using the sample: Test/HelloWorld text strings.

Comment: where is your console.log? Because it may be running your script right when the page loads (which at that time it will be "Test") and then it's not running again after you've changed it. You'll need an on change listener for that.

Comment: I actually figured it out.  I never assigned an ng-model to the input.  binding the value wasnt the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">{{primaryName}}</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{sampleName}} Name" ng-model="name" >
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">{{primaryName}}</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{sampleName}} Name" ng-model="desc" >
</label>
<a ng-click="create()">Create Test</a>

</div>
```

You are not using ng-model , That's why (y)

Comment: if i use the ng-model, im guessing i still need to use value, for setting the default value?

Comment: As you should know , ngModel directive binds an input to a property on the scope , So you dont need it :)